# How do I find the application id of a Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

After creating an App Engine application on Google Cloud Platform, where can I find the application id?

This is in order to populate:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <version>1</version>
    <application>    ?    </application>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to provide this property if you're using `gcloud`.

The Project ID used to be an explicit requirement with older tooling (which is why it's referred to as `application` rather than `projectId`) but it is no longer needed if you use `gcloud`.

This is because `gcloud` either takes the value implicitly from `gcloud config get-value project` or, explicitly when provided during deployment, i.e. `gcloud app deploy --project=${PROJECT}`.

If you still wish to determine the Project ID, the easiest way is to use Google Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com), switch to the project you're interest in using the dropdown and then use the hamburger and project settings, or use this link replacing the value of `${PROJECT}`:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings?project=${PROJECT}
```

Or, if you'd prefer to use `gcloud` though this assumes you already know your Project's ID ;-):

```
gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} --format="value(projectId)"
```

If you ever need to find the project's unique number, then you can:

```
gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} --format="value(projectNumber)"
```